# Vulkan: Invalid Shader Module Object

Tags: c, graphics, vulkan

I've written a small Vulkan test app to familiarize myself Vulkan though I've run into an issue trying to create a pipeline.

vkCreateGraphicsPipeline causes the Validation Layer to produce the following errors:
Invalid Shader Module Object 0x8
Invalid Shader Module Object 0x9

And then it the program crashes within the validation layer.
I had created a VkShaderModule for the vertex shader and fragment shader and used glslangvalidator -V to convert them to SPIR-V modules which vkCreateShaderModule didn't complain about.

Is there anything I may've missed? The examples seem to be doing things exactly the same way I am.

Comment: You missed showing us the code that actually causes the problem you cite.

Comment: The down vote is extremely inappropriate. The code isn't relevant in this case as there's only one way to go about creating a Shader Module and specifying it for a pipeline. It's also not practical due to the verbosity the Vulkan API. Although the error message itself is quite vague it likely has a very specific cause and doubtlessly others have encountered it before and should know exactly what scenario causes it.

Comment: If that's true, then you're basically assuming that the validation layer is broken in some way. And yet, if people couldn't create graphics pipelines at all, then nobody would be able to use validation layers. Of course, people *are* using validation layers, so there cannot be a general problem creating graphics pipelines from shader modules. And therefore, unless there is some reason to suspect otherwise, we *must assume* that your code is at fault. So we need to see what your code actually is doing, no matter how verbose it may be.

Comment: Well, the layers shouldn't crash (except some notable cases). ; Saying that and seeing the error message it makes me think it **is** one of them. It looks like a Object Tracker error. Your `VkShaderModule` handles are invalid for some reason. Show how you create them. Did you perhaps forget to check `VkResult` for `SUCCESS`? Also perhaps check if you are enabling layers in correct order (e.g. through the standard_validation meta-layer).

Comment: Yep it's the handle. I wasn't clear on what the message was referring to and thought it may've been that the object the handle referred to was invalid in some way but it's actually only the handle itself that the message refers to. Turns out the problem was that I should've marked the copy constructor for the VkShaderModule container class as deleted and the object was getting implicitly destroyed by an copy performed in an STL container.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Gonna answerize it then...

Comment: @atlan: "*Turns out the problem was that I should've marked the copy constructor for the VkShaderModule container class as deleted and the object was getting implicitly destroyed by an copy performed in an STL container.*" Perhaps now you will see why it's important to provide a [mcve] when you ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

The error message and the layer crash behavior points to an invalid Vulkan object handle (e.g. object unsuccessfuly `vkCreate*`d or `vkDestroy`ed before use) as detected by the `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_object_tracker` validation layer.

Validation layers should probably not crash if they are all enabled and that in the prescribed order. That can be ensured by using only `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation` meta-layer.

As in any good validator, error messages are completely unreadable by puny humans.
Standard validation layers are open-sourced in [GitHub/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/layers](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/tree/master/layers), so if in doubt it can be searched for the given message text. Usually it is in `core_validation.cpp` but in your case it would be `object_tracker.cpp`. (The message would be in printf format e.g. "Invalid %s Object 0x%" making it bit harder to search for).